# Solutions to create a cluster split on 2 VMs

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubeadm

I'm looking for some clues on which solution can help me on my problem which is running a kubernetes cluster between 2 VMs.

I'm beginning with Kubernetes and all its possibilities but like everybody I started from a `minikube` single-node cluster to host my 4 containers respectively hosting mongoDB, redis, rabbitMQ and minio.

[image]

The idea is that I need something like `minikube` to create a cluster like this:
[image]
Moreover, these 2 VMs will run on RedHat EL 7 and won't be local and they may be hosted on different machines

**Is it possible to build that architecture with kubeadm?**

Comment: Yes its possible. This will get you started `https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response is **yes**, **it can be achieved with `kubeadm`**, it will allow you to aggregate your different VM/hosts into the cluster in the same way `docker-swarm` does by kind of subscribing them into the cluster.

See [how](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) (thanks @Jason Stanley)

---

#### Some Prerequisites

---

If like me you're on a client infrastructure, implementing your solution '**on-premise**' on a **Red Hat environment**, you'll need two or three things.

- The proper docker environment
- An image registry
- An easy way to configure your cluster

#### Docker environment

First one and because it's a restriction meant by docker and red hat is to use `docker-ee` the enterprise edition which allow support on prod by red hat, which is why most people pay a red hat subscription.

See [typical architecture](https://docs.docker.com/ee/docker-ee-architecture/) using docker-ee and [how to install that on Red Hat](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/rhel/)

#### Local image registry

The other thing is to deploy a `docker registry`, this is an official [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) (documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)) provided by Docker team, `registry` will allow your cluster to pull the image from it - images that you will push inside while setting everything up - note that this is relevant in a restricted environment where your VM/hosts can't have access to internet or use a proxy.

#### Cluster setting tool

One handy tool is using `helm` which allow you to set your cluster easily by referencing which images provide a given service, on which port with which policy.

[Helm documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/)